# Get list of MongoDB documents sorted by collection property length - Spring Boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data

So, I have this repository in MongoDB that holds movies with this structure:

```
title: String
description: String
likes: Set<String>
hates: Set<String>
```

The `likes` & `hates` are a `Set` because they hold a list of `UserIds` - where the user with those `UserIds` are the ones that liked/hated the movie.

I am trying to have my service get all movies from the database, **sorted by the number of likes/hates**. Previously, my structure was different, and `likes`/`hates` were just `Integer`s. Then, getting all sorted movies was easy:

```
public List<MovieDocument> getSortedMovies(SortProperty sortBy, Order order) {
    return moviesRepository.findAll(Sort.by(fromString(order.toString()), sortBy.toString()))
}
```

Where `sortBy` was either `likes` or `hates` and `order` was either `asc` or `desc`, provided by the client of the API.

In the above case, `MoviesRepository` didn't have any custom methods:

```
@Repository
public interface MoviesRepository extends MongoRepository<MovieDocument, String> {}
```

How am I supposed to do that now that `likes` and `hates` are `Set` objects?

Again, what I want is to get all movies sorted by the size of the `likes`/`hates` sets.

1. Can I do that using any of the built-in `MongoRepository` methods? I had a look and didn't see anything useful.
2. Looking at other StackOverflow posts, I saw there is an option to add methods to my `MoviesRepository` with an `Aggregation` annotation. This would look something like:

```
@Aggregation("{$project: { 'like_count': { $size: '$likes' } }}, {$sort: {'like_count': -1}}]")
List<String> getSortedMovieIdsByLikesDesc();
```

However, this does not return the whole `MovieDocument`, but rather it returns the number of likes. In addition to that, it looks like I'd have to create a new custom method for each property/order combination i.e. likes-asc, likes-desc, hates-asc, hates-desc. This feels tedious and not very extensible.

How would I fix the above to return whole documents and is there any other way to do this I'm not considering?

**EDIT**

I tried the following based on input from @rickhg12hs.

```
@Aggregation("{$set: { like_count: { $size: $likes } }}, {$sort: {like_count: -1}}")
List<MovieDocument> getSortedMovieIdsByLikesDesc();

@Aggregation("{$set: { like_count: { $size: $likes } }}, {$sort: {like_count: 1}}")
List<MovieDocument> getSortedMovieIdsByLikesAsc();

@Aggregation("{$set: { hate_count: { $size: $hates } }}, {$sort: {hate_count: -1}}")
List<MovieDocument> getSortedMovieIdsByHatesDesc();

@Aggregation("{$set: { hate_count: { $size: $hates } }}, {$sort: {hate_count: 1}}")
List<MovieDocument> getSortedMovieIdsByHatesAsc();
```

Unfortunately, all four of those methods seem to return the exact same thing when called. Specifically they return the two items that are in the database unordered.

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track.  Exchange your `$project` with `$set` so you don't lose the other fields.

Comment: `List<String> getSortedMovieIdsByLikesDesc()` - the return value is to be `List<MovieDocument>` or `List<Document>`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs that doesn't seem to work, unfortunately. I edited my question with more details about why.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing almost everything right.  Here's an example that does what I think you want.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    // Count likes and hates
    "$set": {
      "likeCount": {
        "$size": "$likes"
      },
      "hateCount": {
        "$size": "$hates"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // Most likes first, split ties with
    // least hates first
    "$sort": {
      "likeCount": -1,
      "hateCount": 1
    }
  },
  //  {
  //    "$project": {
  //      "likeCount": 0,
  //      "hateCount": 0
  //    }
  //  }
])
```

You can uncomment the `"$project"` stage if you want to remove the counts too.

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GbyBC5ejcqj).